# how to store many large multidimensional arrays?

Tags: python-2.7, multidimensional-array, storage

I have a deep learning model which generates an output multidimensional array of size 2x2x4096.
Then there are 40,000 of such outputs for each input image.
How to do this in python?
Hdf5 format seems to be a interesting direction.

Can someone point me to the right direction?

Comment: Are you looking to save space? That depends on the kinds of correlations there are in your data. NetCDF implements HDF5 with lossless compression built-in. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/netCDF4

Comment: Space is not a problem.Ease of usage is the priority.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to use HDF5 with [PyTables](http://www.pytables.org/). Putting an array into a file is as easy as this:

```
import numpy as np
import tables

a = np.arange(100)
h5_file = tables.open_file('my_array.h5', mode='w', titel='many large arrays')
h5_file.create_array('/', 'my_array', a)
h5_file.close()
```

An example with 10 multi dimensional arrays:

```
import numpy as np
import tables

my_arrays = [np.ones((2, 2, 4098)) for x in range(10)]

h5_file = tables.open_file('my_array.h5', mode='w', titel='many large arrays')

for n, arr in enumerate(my_arrays):
    h5_file.create_array('/', 'my_array{}'.format(n), arr)
h5_file.close()
```

Having a look at the file structure with `h5ls`:

```
h5ls my_array.h5
my_array0                Dataset {2, 2, 4098}
my_array1                Dataset {2, 2, 4098}
my_array2                Dataset {2, 2, 4098}
my_array3                Dataset {2, 2, 4098}
my_array4                Dataset {2, 2, 4098}
my_array5                Dataset {2, 2, 4098}
my_array6                Dataset {2, 2, 4098}
my_array7                Dataset {2, 2, 4098}
my_array8                Dataset {2, 2, 4098}
my_array9                Dataset {2, 2, 4098}
```

Reading the data back is easy.

Reading all:

```
import tables

h5_file = tables.open_file('my_arrays.h5', mode='r')

for node in h5_file:

    print(node)
```

Output:

```
/ (RootGroup) ''
/my_array0 (Array(2, 2, 4098)) ''
/my_array1 (Array(2, 2, 4098)) ''
/my_array2 (Array(2, 2, 4098)) ''
/my_array3 (Array(2, 2, 4098)) ''
/my_array4 (Array(2, 2, 4098)) ''
/my_array5 (Array(2, 2, 4098)) ''
/my_array6 (Array(2, 2, 4098)) ''
/my_array7 (Array(2, 2, 4098)) ''
/my_array8 (Array(2, 2, 4098)) ''
/my_array9 (Array(2, 2, 4098)) ''
```

or just one by name:

```
print(h5_file.root.my_array0)
```

Output:

```
/my_array0 (Array(2, 2, 4098)) ''
```

Comment: Will the work for multidimensional arrays(& many of them)?. Please tell me how to read it too.